# edit the ID column to add chr to a number

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, error-handling

I have a vcf file.
It looks like this:
It has a vcf header followed by genotype information.
I want to add chr to third column.
Like now it looks like:

```
21 9825796 21_9825796_C_T_b37
```

I want to add chr in front of third column
so now it should look like:

```
21 9825796 chr21_9825796_C_T_b37
```

[image]
I used this command:

```
awk '{if($0 !~ /^#/) print "chr"$3; else print $3}' chr21_annotate.vcf > chr21_annotate_38_impute.vcf
```

But I am not able to get the desired output.
Can anyone help

Comment: do you wanna append chr to column 3 but also print out the full new line , or just $3 ?

Comment: I want to print everything but just add chr to column 3 and keep the rest information.

Comment: then see my answer below

Comment: Don't post examples as images, post them as text. We can't copy/paste an image to test with. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input, expected output and your attempt to solve the problem yourself so we can help you further. See [ask] and look at existing questions that have been upvoted and answered for examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU `sed` solution, let `file.txt` content be

```
# this is header
21 9825796 21_9825796_C_T_b37
21 9825796 21_9825796_C_T_b37
```

then

```
sed -e '/^#/n' -e 's/\([^[:space:]]*\)/chr\1/3' file.txt
```

output

```
# this is header
21 9825796 chr21_9825796_C_T_b37
21 9825796 chr21_9825796_C_T_b37
```

Explanation: I register two expressions using `-e`. First means if line starts with `#` then print it as is and go to next, second replace 3rd occurence of zero or more non-whitespace characters using that occurence prefixed by `chr`. I use capturing group denoted by `\(` and `\)` so I could use its' content in replacement using `\1`.

*(tested in GNU sed 4.2.2)*

Answer (score 2):

```
mawk '/^[^#]/*sub(/^/,"chr",$3)' test.vcf

# comment 1 
21 9825796 21_9825796_C_T_b37
43 82852851 43_82852851_C_T_b37

===before ^ ========after v ========

21 9825796 chr21_9825796_C_T_b37
43 82852851 chr43_82852851_C_T_b37
```

If you wanna try exotic syntax, then

```
mawk '+($3="chr"$3)</^[^#]/'           

# comment 1 
21 9825796 21_9825796_C_T_b37
43 82852851 43_82852851_C_T_b37

===before ^ ========after v ========

21 9825796 chr21_9825796_C_T_b37
43 82852851 chr43_82852851_C_T_b37
```

Comment: I try reading your answers, and looking at the complex ways you write them (in my opinion, but I am just an awk beginner) you are probably very good at it but they seem hard to understand. Your first solution seems pretty nice, but for the second "exotic syntax" one I think it would be a nice addition to  explain it a bit for future readers.

Comment: ' +( $3 = "chr" $3 ) < /^[^#]/  ' ::: it's doing less than "<" comparison ( of any sort ) :  left side I prepend the "chr" text you wanted… by placing the "+" to the left of it, it'll force awk to attempt numeric conversion (NC). but since "chr" is now in front of it, NC of anything not 0-9 always become a numeric zero (0). Right side is common regex checking first char not being hash/pound (#) - ie wanna skip comment lines. Since left side is always FALSE/zero (0), then we need right side to be TRUE (1) in order for this whole expr to also be true. Once true, default pattern action is print.

Comment: the first version of that syntax is just left-right flipping, and checking # first. "Single-bit bit-wise AND" is same  "Logical AND ( && )"  which is same as multiplying the boolean values - that's why u see the regex doing multiply ( * ) against the return value of single-instance substitute func. This variation I use sub( ) to pre-pend the "chr" and avoid having the data re-formatted with a single space of OFS (if that's something important to you). matching criteria in sub( ) is only the start of the line "^", thus a replacement will ALWAYS take place, and right side return value always 1.

Comment: yes, this one also works and give me the correct output

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto Thank you for the detailed explanation, it makes more sense to me now :-)  Should the first `# comment 1` be `# comment 2` ? Sometimes comments under answers and questions are removed. If you want to keep this valuable information you could also add it to the answer.

Comment: @The fourth bird : oh i just wrote them out of order cuz i first focused on answering ur question. If they deem the comment not appropriate enough to keep around, then adding to the main body wouldn't help either since that'll make the entire answer not appropriate, in their view.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you really do have lines that start with `#` somewhere in your input that you don't want to change (per your code) and you don't want to change the white space between fields (per the image you posted) and you want to do it robustly so it works even if earlier fields could contain the same strings as $3 and you want to do it portably then... this will do what you want using any POSIX sed (for the `[:space:]` character class):

```
$ sed 's/^[^#][^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*/&chr/' file
21 9825796 chr21_9825796_C_T_b37
```

If you don't care about changing white space then just do this with any awk:

```
$ awk '!/^#/{$3="chr"$3} 1' file
21 9825796 chr21_9825796_C_T_b37
```

Comment: yes, this one works

Comment: it has a major flaw :  depending on how many leading \f , which counts as whitespace under posix space class, ur regex doesn't guarantee replacing column 3. AWK does automatically as part of leading edge trim. echo '\fabc 123cdf456 ghi78 9jkl'  | sed 's/^[^#][^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*/&chr/' 

abc 123cdf456 chrghi78 9jkl
% echo '\f\fabc 123cdf456 ghi78 9jkl'  | sed 's/^[^#][^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*/&chr/'


abc chr123cdf456 ghi78 9jkl

Comment: You're thinking of some input other than that the OP actually has. If the OP had `\f`s at the start of the `#` lines then none of the posted solutions would work but that's not the input the OP has either and so also isn't worth considering, just like any other input the OP doesn't have.